# Reuse an already used scene in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a scene which opens up when game starts. Lets call this scene 'Start'. It has a new game button which starts the game by loading a new scene. This scene is called 'Game'. After the game ends in 'Game' Scene, I want to open 'Start' scene.

I am using Application.LoadLevel("Start") for this. But when 'Start' scene is opened again all gameobjects are deleted, except the ones I use DontDestroyOnLoad() on. If I pause the game in 'Start' scene, the gameobjects come back but with null in scripts wherever they were assigned in inspector.

I cant use DontDestryOnLoad on every object in 'Start' scene as they are completely useless for the 'Game' scene.

I have also tried Application.LoadLevelAdditive but would give the same result as DontDestroyOnLoad.

Thus the transition that I want is Start -> Game -> Start -> Game ......

And each time the scene may start with fresh gameobjects or reuse the existing ones. But objects in 'Start' are not required in 'Game' scene but only a score object of 'Game' scene is required in 'Start', on which I have applied DontDestroyOnLoad. This object will write the score on an object in 'Start' scene.

Answer (score 2):

Anything that is created in one scene will be destroyed the moment you change scenes, except if the object is `static` or you call `DontDestroyOnLoad()` on that object.

Therefore, it is logically correct to go from `Start --> Game --> Start --> Game` without any side-effects. You must, however, avoid duplicate creations of Objects, for example:

The `Game` scene creates a `Score` object.

```
public class Game : MonoBehaviour 
{
     public GameObject score;

     void Awake()
     {
         score = GameObject.Find("Score");

         if(score == null)
         {
             score = Instantiate(scorePrefab) as GameObject;
             DontDestroyOnLoad(score);
         }
     }
}
```

The code ensures that the next time you reload the `Game` scene, there won't be an extra `Score` object floating around.